# Respond to ajax request with a string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use respond_with in a Rails 4 controller to respond to an ajax request from an AngularJS app.  I just want to return a json web token (string), not an active record object.  How do I do this?

I am getting very weird errors about a url being undefined or location being nil.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Sessions Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    respond_to :json

    def new
    end

    def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
            #login
            token = log_in(user)
        else
            #error
        end
        respond_with(token)
    end

end
```

Route:

```
post 'sessions/create' => 'sessions#create', defaults: { format: :json }
```

Latest error:

```
undefined method 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9_url' for #<SessionsController:0x007ff8d0a42f10>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with the following:

```
render json: token, status: 200
```